# OnStartLocalPlayer() is not overriding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overriding, multiplayer, unity-networking

I make multiplayer script and OnStartLocalPlayer method can't override for some reason. Error:

`Assets\Sharoidi\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(10,26): error CS0115: 'PlayerController.OnStartLocalPlayer()': no suitable method found to override`

Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer() {
        Debug.Log("Local Player started!");
    }
}
```

I tried to delete override, but now method doesn't get called when local player spawns.

Comment: Which Unity version is this?

Comment: 2021.3.9f1 personal

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you're duplicating names of built-in classes and then not getting the results you want because Unity doesn't know which class to use. In your snippet you're defining a class called PlayerController, but [that's already the name of a different class](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.PlayerController.html) and *that* class doesn't have the OnStartLocalPlayer method.

This shouldn't be giving you this particular error, though, but it makes me wonder about your NetworkBehaviour class. That is *also* a built-in class, but it's in the UnityEngine.Networking namespace, which you are not `using` in your snippet. Again, this should give you a different error, that "it's not defined, are you missing an assembly or using statement," but you're not getting that error, which makes me think maybe you have a script somewhere in your project called NetworkBehaviour that's shadowing the built-in.

Try replacing your class declaration with this and see if this does anything different:

```
public class PlayerController : UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour
{
```

This would point explicitly to the built-in NetworkBehaviour. If this fixes it for you then great, but really stop giving your stuff the same names as built-in things.

Comment: I tried to replace class declaration with `UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour`, but there is no NetworkBehaviour in UnityEngine.Networking (error CS0234). Then i tried `Unity.Netcode.NetworkBehaviour`, and it worked, but i still cant override OnStartLocalPlayer method. Also, i'm using unity netcode, not unet, can it be a problem?

Comment: @vala79 It's not the Netcode NetworkBehaviour you're trying to inherit. [This answer on the Unity forums](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1749994/view.html) says to add `using Mirror;`